# R: glm(...,family=poisson) plot confidence and prediction intervals

Tags: r, confidence-interval, poisson-regression, prediction-interval

I could not find many information on how to plot a confidence interval and a prediction interval for a Poisson regression (for example with `glm()`).
What are some ways to calculate such intervals (in general and especially for poisson regression)? Would Bootstrap be a good idea?

Thank you for the help.

And sorry about the edit. It was maybe more of a `R` question before.

Comment: Your edit leaves a post that contains a statement but not a question. Did you mean to ask about ways to generate prediction intervals for Poisson regression/Poisson GLMs in general?

Answer (score 8):

R's predict ought to be able to do a confidence interval for a GLM but definitely won't do a prediction interval -- there's an underlying statistical issue here, which I'll discuss in this answer.

i) For some GLMs it doesn't make sense to even try to do a PI - consider a logistic regression with 0/1 responses, and imagine you want say a 95% PI. Anywhere that E(Y) is not very close to 0 or 1, a prediction interval will have to include all of 0 to 1, and when E(Y) is very close to 0 or 1, the interval degenerates to just a point.

ii) for many other GLMs there's no ready analytic prediction interval. For example, there's generally no pivotal quantity for the prediction like there is in the normal case. The Poisson is among those.

A number of papers have looked at ways to get at approximate prediction intervals for some cases, and there's also options like bootstrapping, but because of issues like those I've mentioned, there's no prediction interval in R's GLM.

[To produce a CI for the mean, see `?predict.glm`; `predict(fit, type="response", se.fit=TRUE)` will give the mean and and standard 
error, which can be used to get an approximate (asympotic) interval. Alternatively, you could use the default `type="link"` and transform an interval for that. ]

Comment: I was initially taken aback by the assertions in (i). After some consideration, I have concluded there is no inherent problem in constructing prediction intervals with GLMs. The issue concerns the *target* of prediction. When the target is a single binary outcome, then obviously not much can be said. But predictions can be made about anything, such as a statistic based on multiple (future) observations: the mean, say, of 100 independent future outcomes. This highlights a missing element from the question: *exactly what are the intended targets of the confidence or prediction intervals*?

Comment: @whuber I think the intended target was clear enough when the original question was asked, but the question has since changed (losing context in attempting to avoid closure). Consequently this answer no longer really answers it. I was hoping to see additional clarification that would allow the answer to be modified and added to in order that it answer the new question by describing some possible ways to do it in principle for Poisson regression (rather than roughly paraphrasing Ripley's terse explanations of why R doesn't do it for individuals).  I wonder now if I should delete instead.